# How to determine what service is executing queries against CosmosDB database?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am working in an environment that has a legacy production Cosmos Database our team is wanting to shut down. Based on Cosmos's metrics and logs we can clearly see inserts and upserts still hitting a container, however, we cannot determine where the requests are coming from (i.e. what app service).

Is there a way to determine what app service queries are coming from using the Logs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Logs` for Cosmos DB account from `AzureDiagnostics` source and `Category == "DataPlaneRequests"` extract `clientIdAdress_s` and `userAgent_s` to identify source of the request.

Following query will return list of IPs and requests (Read, Create, Query, etc.):

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.DOCUMENTDB" and Category == "DataPlaneRequests"
| project clientIpAddress_s, userAgent_s, requestResourceId_s, OperationName
```

Adding where clause `OperationName == "Create"` will return only inserts in the result set. Also it might be useful to add filters by `requestResourceId` to focus on specific datqbase in multi-DB account.